# Heavy load on worker thread causes multiple icons

Tags: c#

I have a small issue and I will explain  as best as I can.

I have an application with several threads running for several things. This is a system tray based application so no forms will be loaded when you load the program. Here comes the fun part. I decided to put some load on the worker thread because I was unable to create a new thread for the work I had to be done. I have a loading screen also so when I open up the form and the heavy work starts my application icons multiplies like 5 times and it looks like it creates a new instance of the application but not a new process. Even if I build the project and run it from there it does the same thing.

I have had more load on the worker `thread` before and it didn't cause this but now when I added `threads` for the other work and put a new line of work on the worker thread it suddenly behave like this.

What could be the issue?

SOLVED: Well I was kinda stupid because i started several instances instead of using the current one. My bad.

Comment: Very vague question. Have you tried to put a breakpoint where you show tray icon and debug?

Comment: Well no. But ive tried to remove the function that runs when I open the form which causes the icon to duplicate a few times. When I did that it stoped duplicating. The function I have is just looping through an array of 5 items and making tcp calls to a website and get some information and then stores it in some varibles. Thats all it does.

Comment: Sounds like a logic flaw in your application.

Comment: answer your question if it's solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Well I was kinda stupid because i started several instances instead of using the current one. My bad.